# Access external IP google cloud windows instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have got the info as:

> Each instance can also have an external IP address, which is rout-able over the Internet.

described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking).

But when I click the following arrow:

[image]

It shows **The connection has timed out** while I have enabled HTTP/ HTTPS access in console.

The firewall rules that have been applied are:

[image]

I have promoted external IP address to static **but not able to get internet access** for my Oracle Apex application.

Comment: What is your actual question? Something that ends with a "?" ...

Comment: success to get internet access

Comment: Sorry, but that is still **not** a question, and you should EDIT your question to actually include your real question (instead of adding extra comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope [this](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/managing-the-windows-server-2012-firewall/) help

> The Windows Firewall with Advanced Security is a host-based firewall that runs on Windows Server 2012 and is turned on by default. Firewall
> settings within Windows Server 2012 are managed from within the
> Windows Firewall MMC (Microsoft Management Console). To review and set
> Firewall settings perform the following:
>
> 1. Open the Server Manager from the task bar.
> 2. List item Click the Tools menu and select Windows Firewall with Advanced Security.
>
> From the right side of either the Inbound Rules or Outbound Rules
> **tab click **New Rule.
>
> Select Custom from the Rule Type radial button and click Next.
>
> Select the Program association for the Custom Firewall Rule as either All programs or the path to a program and click Next.
>
> From the Protocol type field select the protocol type and click Next.
>
> Select an IP address association for both local and remote addresses and click Next.
>
> Select an action to take on matching traffic and click Next.
>
> Select the profiles associated with the custom rule and click Next.
>
> Provide a name for your Firewall rule and an optional description and click Finish.
>
> Once created, the rule will be enabled. The firewall rule can be found on the corresponding Rule tab, either inbound or outbound
> depending on the type created. To disable or delete the rule find the
> rule in the MMC, right-click it, and select either Disable Rule or
> Delete.